# Split windows 7 screen into smaller sections

Tags: desktop-management

Once a upon a time I had an app that would allow you do divide up your monitor into small sections so when you hit the maximize button the window would only take up one section.

Any idea of how or what that app was called?

Answer (score 1):

Was it [PowerResizer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/powerresizer/)?

Otherwise, I found a list of similar programs at http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/best-free-window-manager-resizer-arranger.htm 
Check out the **Window Sizing/Arranging Programs** section

Answer (score 0):

The best (and working) for me was [Acer GridVista](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/Acer-Gridvista-Download-71638.html)

> This application makes more effective use of large monitors by
>   dividing them into sections where you can place your windows