# Windows split screen into unequal sides?

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop, window-manager

When one drags and drops a window to either side of the screen, it automatically snaps to that side, filling 50% of the screen. Is there a way to override this value in the settings/registry? I have an ultra-wide screen, and would prefer if Windows snapped windows *automatically* to roughly 1/3-2/3.

Alternatively, I am interested in a software solution as well. I found Acer GridVista and PowerResizer under [this](https://superuser.com/questions/464054/split-windows-7-screen-into-smaller-sections) question, is any of them capable of this?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/inside-this-update-93c5c27c-f96e-43c2-a08e-5812d92f220d and scroll halfway down and in Win 11 you hover over the maximise button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this may be what you are looking for https://www.howtogeek.com/706007/how-to-snap-windows-to-custom-screen-regions-on-windows-10/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! Also the link contains a thorough manual.